# How do I get the change picture arrows to be on the sides of the picture?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a picture slideshow that has arrow buttons that allow the user to go to the next or last image. How do I get these arrows to be on or in the picture on the appropriate side (left middle for previous image and right middle for next image)? 
Here is my current code:

```
     <head>
  <title>change picture</title>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
          document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
      }

      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 6000);
      }
      function startUp(){
      document.getElementById("img").src = images[0];
      }

      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = "image1.jpg";
      images[1] = "image2.jpg";
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload = "startTimer(); startUp()">
   <button type="button" onclick="displayPreviousImage()"> &laquo</button>
   <img id="img" style="width:500px;height:380px;" src="startpicture.jpg">
  <button type="button" onclick="displayNextImage()"> &raquo</button>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your image in a container to get an HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="imgContainer">
     <button class="leftButton"></button>
     <img class="slideshowImage">
     <button class="rightButton"></button>
</div>
```

Then apply CSS such as this one:

```
 .imgContainer {
   position: relative;
 }

 .leftButton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; bottom: 50%;
 }
  .rightButton {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; bottom: 50%;
 }
```

By specifying the `position` property of your buttons to be `absolute`, you're making them position themselves relative to their closest parent with an `absolute` or `relative` position.
This is why we set `.imgContainer`'s position to `relative`.
We can now position the buttons within the container with the `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` properties.

Check this article for a more in-depth explanation: [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

Perfect vertical centering of the buttons is more tricky and requires yet another hack so for now you can just use the `bottom: 50%;`, or dive into the art of [Centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) when you feel ready.